# Windows Forms sizing issue when migrating from a 32bit to 64bit

Tags: c#, winforms, 64-bit

We are migrating a 32bit WinForms app to 64bit.  Given identical OS and screen-resolution, we've noticed that the application shell in it's maximized state overflows the monitor in the x64 version, but works fine in the x32 version.  Why does this happen please?  Is there some issue with the migration that could have caused this?

Our code in the .designer.cs file:

```
 private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.components = new System.ComponentModel.Container();
            Infragistics.Win.Appearance appearance11 = new Infragistics.Win.Appearance();
            Infragistics.Win.Appearance appearance12 = new Infragistics.Win.Appearance();
            this._ShellForm_Toolbars_Dock_Area_Left = new Infragistics.Win.UltraWinToolbars.UltraToolbarsDockArea();
            this.stableRibbonManager = new Infragistics.Win.UltraWinToolbars.UltraToolbarsManager(this.components);
            this._ShellForm_Toolbars_Dock_Area_Right = new Infragistics.Win.UltraWinToolbars.UltraToolbarsDockArea();
            this._ShellForm_Toolbars_Dock_Area_Top = new Infragistics.Win.UltraWinToolbars.UltraToolbarsDockArea();
            this._ShellForm_Toolbars_Dock_Area_Bottom = new Infragistics.Win.UltraWinToolbars.UltraToolbarsDockArea();
            this.stableShellStatus = new Infragistics.Win.UltraWinStatusBar.UltraStatusBar();
            this.contentWorkspace = new CABExtensions.CustomWorkspaces.DockingWorkspace(this.components);
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.stableRibbonManager)).BeginInit();
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.stableShellStatus)).BeginInit();
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // _ShellForm_Toolbars_Dock_Area_Left
            // 
            this._ShellForm_Toolbars_Dock_Area_Left.AccessibleRole = System.Windows.Forms.AccessibleRole.Grouping;
            this._ShellForm_Toolbars_Dock_Area_Left.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(191)))), ((int)(((byte)(219)))), ((int)(((byte)(255)))));
            this._ShellForm_Toolbars_Dock_Area_Left.DockedPosition = Infragistics.Win.UltraWinToolbars.DockedPosition.Left;
            this._ShellForm_Toolbars_Dock_Area_Left.ForeColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.ControlText;
            this._ShellForm_Toolbars_Dock_Area_Left.InitialResizeAreaExtent = 8;
            this._ShellForm_Toolbars_Dock_Area_Left.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 55);
            this._ShellForm_Toolbars_Dock_Area_Left.Name = "_ShellForm_Toolbars_Dock_Area_Left";
            this._ShellForm_Toolbars_Dock_Area_Left.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(8, 920);
            this._ShellForm_Toolbars_Dock_Area_Left.ToolbarsManager = this.stableRibbonManager;
            // 
            // stableRibbonManager
            // 
            this.stableRibbonManager.DesignerFlags = 1;
            this.stableRibbonManager.DockWithinContainer = this;
            this.stableRibbonManager.DockWithinContainerBaseType = typeof(System.Windows.Forms.Form);
            this.stableRibbonManager.Ribbon.Visible = true;
            // 
            // _ShellForm_Toolbars_Dock_Area_Right
            // 
            this._ShellForm_Toolbars_Dock_Area_Right.AccessibleRole = System.Windows.Forms.AccessibleRole.Grouping;
            this._ShellForm_Toolbars_Dock_Area_Right.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(191)))), ((int)(((byte)(219)))), ((int)(((byte)(255)))));
            this._ShellForm_Toolbars_Dock_Area_Right.DockedPosition = Infragistics.Win.UltraWinToolbars.DockedPosition.Right;
            this._ShellForm_Toolbars_Dock_Area_Right.ForeColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.ControlText;
            this._ShellForm_Toolbars_Dock_Area_Right.InitialResizeAreaExtent = 8;
            this._ShellForm_Toolbars_Dock_Area_Right.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(1192, 55);
            this._ShellForm_Toolbars_Dock_Area_Right.Name = "_ShellForm_Toolbars_Dock_Area_Right";
            this._ShellForm_Toolbars_Dock_Area_Right.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(8, 920);
            this._ShellForm_Toolbars_Dock_Area_Right.ToolbarsManager = this.stableRibbonManager;
            // 
            // _ShellForm_Toolbars_Dock_Area_Top
            // 
            this._ShellForm_Toolbars_Dock_Area_Top.AccessibleRole = System.Windows.Forms.AccessibleRole.Grouping;
            this._ShellForm_Toolbars_Dock_Area_Top.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(191)))), ((int)(((byte)(219)))), ((int)(((byte)(255)))));
            this._ShellForm_Toolbars_Dock_Area_Top.DockedPosition = Infragistics.Win.UltraWinToolbars.DockedPosition.Top;
            this._ShellForm_Toolbars_Dock_Area_Top.ForeColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.ControlText;
            this._ShellForm_Toolbars_Dock_Area_Top.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
            this._ShellForm_Toolbars_Dock_Area_Top.Name = "_ShellForm_Toolbars_Dock_Area_Top";
            this._ShellForm_Toolbars_Dock_Area_Top.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(1200, 55);
            this._ShellForm_Toolbars_Dock_Area_Top.ToolbarsManager = this.stableRibbonManager;
            // 
            // _ShellForm_Toolbars_Dock_Area_Bottom
            // 
            this._ShellForm_Toolbars_Dock_Area_Bottom.AccessibleRole = System.Windows.Forms.AccessibleRole.Grouping;
            this._ShellForm_Toolbars_Dock_Area_Bottom.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(191)))), ((int)(((byte)(219)))), ((int)(((byte)(255)))));
            this._ShellForm_Toolbars_Dock_Area_Bottom.DockedPosition = Infragistics.Win.UltraWinToolbars.DockedPosition.Bottom;
            this._ShellForm_Toolbars_Dock_Area_Bottom.ForeColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.ControlText;
            this._ShellForm_Toolbars_Dock_Area_Bottom.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 975);
            this._ShellForm_Toolbars_Dock_Area_Bottom.Name = "_ShellForm_Toolbars_Dock_Area_Bottom";
            this._ShellForm_Toolbars_Dock_Area_Bottom.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(1200, 0);
            this._ShellForm_Toolbars_Dock_Area_Bottom.ToolbarsManager = this.stableRibbonManager;
            // 
            // stableShellStatus
            // 
            appearance11.ImageVAlign = Infragistics.Win.VAlign.Middle;
            appearance11.TextVAlignAsString = "Bottom";
            this.stableShellStatus.Appearance = appearance11;
            this.stableShellStatus.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 975);
            this.stableShellStatus.Name = "stableShellStatus";
            appearance12.ImageVAlign = Infragistics.Win.VAlign.Middle;
            appearance12.TextVAlignAsString = "Middle";
            this.stableShellStatus.PanelAppearance = appearance12;
            this.stableShellStatus.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(1200, 25);
            this.stableShellStatus.TabIndex = 11;
            this.stableShellStatus.ButtonClick += new Infragistics.Win.UltraWinStatusBar.PanelEventHandler(this.stableShellStatus_ButtonClick);
            // 
            // contentWorkspace
            // 
            this.contentWorkspace.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightSteelBlue;
            this.contentWorkspace.BorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
            this.contentWorkspace.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
            this.contentWorkspace.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(8, 55);
            this.contentWorkspace.Name = "contentWorkspace";
            this.contentWorkspace.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(1184, 920);
            this.contentWorkspace.TabIndex = 21;
            // 
            // ShellForm
            // 
            this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
            this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
            this.BackgroundImageLayout = System.Windows.Forms.ImageLayout.Stretch;
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(1200, 1000);
            this.Controls.Add(this.contentWorkspace);
            this.Controls.Add(this._ShellForm_Toolbars_Dock_Area_Left);
            this.Controls.Add(this._ShellForm_Toolbars_Dock_Area_Right);
            this.Controls.Add(this._ShellForm_Toolbars_Dock_Area_Top);
            this.Controls.Add(this._ShellForm_Toolbars_Dock_Area_Bottom);
            this.Controls.Add(this.stableShellStatus);
            this.DoubleBuffered = true;
            this.MinimumSize = new System.Drawing.Size(1200, 1000);
            this.Name = "ShellForm";
            this.StartPosition = System.Windows.Forms.FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
            this.Text = "My System";
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.stableRibbonManager)).EndInit();
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.stableShellStatus)).EndInit();
            this.ResumeLayout(false);
}
```

Any inputs would really help.

Comment: note: '32bit' is usually called x86, strange I know, but that is the convention. Issues like this is probably best approached by debugging. Is the windows version identical? Is it reproducible on other machines? VMs can be great for testing such things. Register an event handler for the sizeChanged event, can you see anything different on the two platforms?

Comment: Yes windows version win7 is identical, it's reproducible on all machines.  sizeChanged here doesnt really apply right coz both initially have set windowsState to Maximized?

Comment: Presumably, maximizing the window should cause the size to change. If the size is different you want to know *why*, i.e. try to find the value that is different between the platforms, and see if it has anything to do with your code, or the framework code.

Comment: Ok let me try that.  One thing have found is a colleague with lower screen resolution, there seems to be more of an overflow.  That is, there more area of the edges getting cut off the monitor

Comment: Checked the size changed event for x86 versus x64 and the properties look the same.  
x64
AutoScaleDimensions = {Width = 6 Height = 13}
AutoSizeMode = GrowOnly
AutoScroll = false
ClientRectangle = {X = 0 Y = 0 Width = 1936 Height = 1056}
DefaultMargin = {{Left=3,Top=3,Right=3,Bottom=3}}
DesktopBounds = {X = -8 Y = -8 Width = 1936 Height = 1056}
DeviceDpi = 96
DpiAwarenessContext = DPI_AWARENESS_CONTEXT_UNSPECIFIED
Font = {Name = "Microsoft Sans Serif" Size=8.25}
FontHeight = 13
Left = -8
Location = {X = -8 Y = -8}
Size = {Width = 1936 Height = 1056}
Top = -8
Width = 1936

Comment: x86
AutoScaleDimensions = {Width = 6 Height = 13}
Bounds = {X = -8 Y = -8 Width = 1936 Height = 1056}
ClientRectangle = {X = 0 Y = 0 Width = 1936 Height = 1056}
ClientSize  = {Width = 1936 Height = 1056}
DefaultMargin = {{Left=3,Top=3,Right=3,Bottom=3}}
DesktopBounds = {X = -8 Y = -8 Width = 1936 Height = 1056}
DeviceDpi = 96
DpiAwarenessContext = DPI_AWARENESS_CONTEXT_UNSPECIFIED
Font = {Name = "Microsoft Sans Serif" Size=8.25}
FontHeight = 13
Left = -8
Location = {X = -8 Y = -8}
Size = {Width = 1936 Height = 1056}
Top = -8
Width = 1936

Comment: Any ideas what else i could check please?

Comment: There's one more thing i found: as part of upgrade, I migrated .Net framework from 4.0 to 4.7.  Even version 4.5 is causing issue.  With 4.0 it works fine, seems any higher is breaking screen resolution.

Comment: Are your controls nested a lot? There is actually a well known issue with sizing when people move from 32bit to 64bit systems. One is related to the nested controls.
 I see infragistics there. Do you load some hierarchical data that forces multilayered controls? Do you add other user controls that have nested controls in them?